# copy data from a memory address to another memory address, 752 bytes at a time

Tags: c

i want to copy data from a memory address to another memory address, 752 bytes at a time . without the for loop i am able to copy 752 bytes just once. how do i do it again and again 480 times and i need to increment my destination address so that all the 752 bytes data gets stored one after another in destination memory block. how can i do that? this is the solution that i came up with but its not working please help. Thank you .

```
volatile unsigned char *DAQ_BUFF = (unsigned char *)0xC6010000;
extern unsigned char *DAQ_BUFF;
unsigned char *Dest = (unsigned char *)0xC6020000;
int lv;
for(lv=0;lv<480;lv++)
{
    memcpy(Dest,DAQ_BUFF,752);

    Dest=Dest+752;
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to advance `DAQ_BUFF`?

Comment: where is the destination memory pointing to ??

Comment: Why do you copy in three parts?  Please indent your code, this looks bad (partly due to TABs, which you should not use).

Comment: You should really look into some basics about Pointers and References. Your variable `Dest` is already a pointer. Same for your variable `DAQ_BUFF`. Since `memcpy` expects a pointer for Destionation and Source, there is no need to use the reference operator for them. You actually pass `char**` to `memcpy`...

Comment: firstly thanks guys for helping me out. Yes the data in the DAQ_BUFF is read from FPGA(feild Programmable Gate Array) and i cant increment DAQ_BUFF because of the limited bytes that are getting transferred from fpga to the dsp(digital signal processor) i.e. acnt is restricted. is it possible to not increment DAQ_BUFF and only increment Dest to store the same DAQ_BUFF data into Dest again and again ?

Comment: sorry for not defining *Dest . Now it is defined

Comment: All you have to do is remove the `&` from `&Dest` and `&DAQ_BUFF`. Dest and DAQ_BUFF are already pointers. They point to `0xC6010000` and `0xC6020000`. These values are put in variables named `Dest` and `DAQ_BUFF`. These values are located at (example) `0x000010` and `0x000014`. If you do `&Dest` you pass the location `Dest` which is `0x000010` instead of its value `0xC6020000`. So just remove the `&` and your code should work.

Comment: guys this is also not working. yes it works just fine for one loop perfectly. but its not working for 480 loops. has anybody got any more suggestions. thanks in advance.

Comment: 'is not working' is not a really helpful message don't you think? 'what' is not working? Do you have debugging tools? can you describe what is, what is not and what you expected to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Four things i noticed:

You are using memcpy 3 times
You dont increment DAQ_BUFF as Rowland said
You are using memcpy(&Dest,&DAQ_BUFF,300); instead of memcpy(Dest,DAQ_BUFF,300);
And Dest is not initialized

```
unsigned char *Dest = something;  
int lv;  
for(lv = 0; lv < 480; lv++){  
    memcpy(Dest, DAQ_BUFF, 752);  
    Dest += 752;  
    DAQ_BUFF += 752;  
}
```

valter

Comment: `DAQ_BUFF` is probably not incremented because it's pointing to a hardware FIFO, so subsequent reads get different data.

Comment: But he didnt say anything. How should we know.

Comment: and it might even be possible that this DAQ buffer is only 300 bytes large (not uncommon on (probably) microcontrollers/small processor)

Comment: Yes indeed. When i saw `(unsigned char *)0xC6010000` my first thought was embedded systems, assembly etc.

Comment: firstly thanks guys for helping me out. Yes the data in the DAQ_BUFF is read from FPGA(feild Programmable Gate Array) and i cant increment DAQ_BUFF because of the limited bytes that are getting transferred from fpga to the dsp(digital signal processor) i.e. acnt is restricted. is it possible to not increment DAQ_BUFF and only increment Dest to store the same DAQ_BUFF data into Dest again and again ?

Comment: I cant say anything because i am not familiar with this but if it is a hardware issue you should see the manual perhaps? Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

I think that small change in your loop will satisfy the situation

Here is the modified loop

```
volatile unsigned char *DAQ_BUFF = (unsigned char *)0xC6010000;
extern unsigned char *DAQ_BUFF;
unsigned char *Dest;
int lv,rv;

for(lv=0;lv<480;lv++)
{
    memcpy(&Dest,&DAQ_BUFF+752*lv,300);
    memcpy(&Dest+300,&DAQ_BUFF+300+752*lv,300);
    memcpy(&Dest+600,&DAQ_BUFF+600+752*lv,152);
    Dest=Dest+752;
}
```

Comment: `*Dest` is still not initialized which results in undefined behaviour (probably initialized to *0, EG NULL-pointer)

Comment: You're right. But this was not the problem as presented. I guess that the code was stripped from large file.

Comment: Why are you adding +752 to &DAG_BUFF?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work, see my comment on your question for an explanation. Can you explain to me why the memcpy only goes in steps of 300 bytes?

```
volatile unsigned char *DAQ_BUFF = (unsigned char *)0xC6010000;
extern unsigned char *DAQ_BUFF;
unsigned char *Dest = (unsigned char *)0xC6020000;
int lv;

for(lv=0;lv<480;lv++)
{
    memcpy(Dest, DAQ_BUFF, 300);
    memcpy(Dest+300, DAQ_BUFF+300, 300);
    memcpy(Dest+600, DAQ_BUFF+600, 152);
    Dest += 752;
}
```

Your code makes me assume that `DAQ_BUFF` is large enough to hold 752 bytes. The reason for me to assume this is because there is no signal/flag checking to see if the 'next 300' bytes of data is 'valid' in your `DAQ_BUFF`. If you do need to check this I would have expected something like this:

```
for(lv=0;lv<480;lv++)
{
    while (DAQ_BUFF_DATA_IS_NOT_VALID); /* wait for DAQ data to be valid */
    memcpy(Dest, DAQ_BUFF, 300);

    /* if DAQ_BUFF can only hold 300 bytes then it must be read from the beginning again */
    while (DAQ_BUFF_DATA_IS_NOT_VALID); /* wait for DAQ data to be valid */
    memcpy(Dest+300, DAQ_BUFF, 300);

    while (DAQ_BUFF_DATA_IS_NOT_VALID); /* wait for DAQ data to be valid */
    memcpy(Dest+600, DAQ_BUFF, 152);

    Dest += 752;
}
```

That seems more like a piece of code that has a `DAQ_BUFFER_SIZE` of 300.

If that is not the case and your `DAQ_BUFFER_SIZE` is large enough to commodate the 752 bytes I would expect the following:

```
for(lv=0;lv<480;lv++)
{
    /* Do you first need to check if DAQ_BUFF-data is valid? */
    memcpy(Dest, DAQ_BUFF, 752);

    Dest += 752;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}
int *p = a;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
      printf("array value is %d pointer poiniting to %p ",*(p+i),p);
}
```

if you run this code everytime the value of p will be same 
as u are incrementing the pointer only adding it. fix the incrementation either like

```
p = p+1;
p++;
```

In your case Dest and DAQ_BUFF.

Note: check if you have initialized the pointers correctly.(May be the code is missing )
or it will pointing to random memory